# Jquery Accordion Horizontal Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Can the default Jquery accordion function be used to implement horizontal accordions... if yes then kindly point me to the suitaible documentation .. if not suggest an appropriate one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `default` accordion of jQuery UI
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ there is **no** horizontal option in the jQuery UI version.

here is one who does work horizontal: http://www.portalzine.de/index?/Horizontal_Accordion

and here are several more:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

or you can join the jQuery UI workspace: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137702/Accordion